# Making a maven project with spring dependencies which are build from source

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

I want to look into springframework implementation. So I followed link:

[building springframework from source](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework#building-from-source)

Following this link, I was able to build various spring modules.And I successfully imported these projects in my eclipse workspace.
To exlpore the code, I made a maven based spring MVC project in same Eclipse workspace where I have imported spring framework projects.And I added spring projects as build path dependencies to MVC project.But when I execute(clean install -e) pom.xml for MVC project, compilation issues are shown for all the springframework references I am making from my code, like packages don't exist,symbols not found etc. Here is my simple java code:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Home {

    String message = "Welcome to your 1st Maven Spring project !";  

    @RequestMapping("/hello")  
    public ModelAndView showMessage() {  
        System.out.println("from controller");  
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);  
    }  

}
```

What can be the reason?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.manish.springrestful</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringRestful</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>SpringRestful Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>SpringRestful</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>my-tomcat</server>
                <path>/SpringRestful</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can you show the `pom.xml` of your project ?

Comment: Try adding the spring dependencies in your pom.xml instead as a build path dependencies.

Comment: The springframework source is a gradle project which your are adding to the build path dependency of your maven project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the required maven Spring framework dependencies(from maven repository) in your `pom.xml` instead of configuring it in the build path of the project.

Comment: Thanks for tip. It compiles now.But how can I debug the springframework source code now?

Comment: In your project go to maven-> download source. After that you can put break points in the Springframework code itself.